# How to form a matrix from one column in a file?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have a file that contains this column of info

```
1.0000000000000002
0.6593496737729044
1.0000000000000002
```

I can read this data from a file and I want to form a matrix 2*2 from it. I tried a lot, but I got a wrong output.

```
my code 
with open("final_overlap.txt", "r") as final_over:
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
                    i = final_over.readline()
                    j = final_over.readline()
                    S = np.array([i,j])
                    print(S)
```

```
     The output I want like this.
        
            [[1.0000000000000002   0.6593496737729044]
             [0.6593496737729044   1.0000000000000002]]


How can I form this matrix.

Take into account that I have another input, and it has more info, so I want a method that can form a different matrix not only 2*2.
Like this input too

  

        1    1      1.0000000000000002
        2    1      0.6593496737729044
        2    2      1.0000000000000002
        3    1      0.1192165290691592
        3    2      0.0954901018165798
        3    3      1.0000000000000002
        4    1      0.0954901018165798
        4    2      0.1192165290691592
        4    3      0.6593496737729044
        4    4      1.0000000000000002

and the matrix will be 4*4
```

One more question about the matrix. I got the right answer but if I have input like this.
`

```
    1    1    1    1      0.7746059439198979
    2    1    1    1      0.4441350695399573
    2    1    2    1      0.2970603935859659
    2    2    1    1      0.5696940113278337
    2    2    2    1      0.4441350695399575
    2    2    2    2      0.7746059439198979
```

I tried with this code, but I got error "list index out of range"

```
for line in open('Two_Electron.txt'):
    r,c,d,e,v = line.split()
    r = int(r)-1
    c = int(c)-1
    d = int(d)-1
    e = int(e)-1    
    v = float(v)
    if c == 0:
        data.append( [v] )
    else:
        data[-1].append(v)

print(data)

# Fill in the upper triangle.

for i in range(len(data)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
        data[i].append( data[j][i] )
        for k in range(len(data)-1):
            for l in range(k+1,len(data)):
                data[k].append( data[l][k] )

V_ee = np.array(data)
```

The output should I get.

```
 [[[[0.77460594 0.4441351 ]
   [0.4441351  0.56969403]]

  [[0.4441351  0.29706043]
   [0.29706043 0.4441351 ]]]


 [[[0.4441351  0.29706043]
   [0.29706043 0.4441351 ]]

  [[0.56969403 0.4441351 ]
   [0.4441351  0.77460594]]]]
```

Comment: You have described this problem very poorly.  Clearly, what you have here is a lower triangular matrix.  Do you want the upper triangle to be zero, or do you really want it to be a reflection of the lower part?

Comment: @TimRoberts
No, I have the input the last one I added in the post where the first column and second column are the index of matrix that I want to form,  but as you see that in the input, not all the elements are written in the input as some values are the same as 2,1 index == 1,2 index so I want to do a loop or code that can form a matrix whatever is the size

Comment: But, you see, it's not just that "not all the elements are written".  This is a VERY SPECIFIC format.  You have 1s on the main diagonal.  All the elements below the diagonal are present, and all the elements above the diagonal are not.  That's a "lower triangular matrix".  I assume you just want the lower triangle reflected across the diagonal to the upper triangle, and that's what I've done below.

Comment: @TimRoberts  Exactly. Now it is the correct. This is what I want
Thank you so much

Comment: @TimRoberts. Sorry for that. I did another edit in the post. Can you see what is my mistake?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the data into a simple list, then build the rows from the list.

```
with open("final_overlap.txt", "r") as final_over:
    data = [float(line) for line in final_over]

S = np.array( [data[0:2], data[1:]] )
print(S)
```

Output:

```
[[1.         0.65934967]
 [0.65934967 1.        ]]
```

**Followup**

OK, assuming your data has row and column numbers like your second example, this will read the data, fill in the upper triangle, and convert to np.array.

```
import numpy as np

# Read in the data to find out the size.

data = []

for line in open('x.txt'):
    r,c,v = line.split()
    r = int(r)-1
    c = int(c)-1
    v = float(v)
    if c == 0:
        data.append( [v] )
    else:
        data[-1].append(v)

# Fill in the upper triangle.

for i in range(len(data)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
        data[i].append( data[j][i] )

array = np.array(data)
print(array)
```

Output:

```
[[1.         0.65934967 0.11921653 0.0954901 ]
 [0.65934967 1.         0.0954901  0.11921653]
 [0.11921653 0.0954901  1.         0.65934967]
 [0.0954901  0.11921653 0.65934967 1.        ]]
```

It would still be possible to do this, even if you don't have the row and column numbers, just by keeping an internal counter.

Comment: But is there any other method that can depend on a shape of array as I have not only matrix 2*2, but also I have 4*4 and 8*8 for different data.

Comment: If you can see the edit in the post.